# Ajax Обрыв запроса

Tags: javascript, php

Вообщем есть у меня один проект в нём я для загрузки фото и ссылок на видео использую ajax.

Код для загрузки картинок:

```
function uploadFoto() {
    clearFotoVideoErrorMessage(true);
    clearFotoVideoSuccessMessage(true);

    let file_data = $('.js-fotovideo_add__form-file').prop('files');
    let form_data = new FormData();

    form_data.append('cl_name', 'userfotovideo');
    form_data.append('me_name', 'uploadFotos');
    form_data.append('id_books', getIdBooksFromUrl());

    ...

    setFotoIsLoading(true);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/ajax.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        data: form_data,
        success: function(data) {
            if (data != null || data !== '') {
                if (data.errors.length > 0) {
                    data.errors.forEach((error) => {
                        addFotoVideoErrorMessage(error.message, true)
                    });
                }

                if (data.result.length > 0) {
                    data.result.forEach((file, index) => {
                        createPhotoElement(file, index, true);
                    });

                    setPhotoCount(photo_count + data.result.length);
                }
            } else {
                addFotoVideoErrorMessage('Произошла неизвестная ошибка', true);
            }

            disablePublicButton();
            checkDisableLimitButtonPhoto();
        },
        error: function (errors) {
            addFotoVideoErrorMessage(errors.message, true);
            setFotoIsLoading(false);
        },
        complete: function () {
            setFotoIsLoading(false);
            $('.b-foto-lightbox-foto-box > .b-foto-lightbox-loading').remove();
        }
    });
}
```

Она немного длинная и запустанная, по этому я её укоротил.

Вообщем бывают моменты когда у меня запрос просто прерывается, и ответ приходит пустым, т.е. фактически статус ответа 200, а data пустой. Я пытался это отфильтровать, но не получилось, а что более важно я так и не смог найти в чем причина. Кто знает из-за чего может такое быть или в какую сторону стоит капать ??

Comment: Капать никуда не надо, а кОпать нужно в сторону получения ответа от сервера в первую очередь, во вторую - ошибка запроса, и напоследок - логи сервера.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov Ну ошибок запроса нет, он же выполняется нормально, просто иногда у него случается такое.

Comment: Сталкивался с таким, когда была слишком долгая работа кода (в php) и она выходила за 30 секунд, установленные по умолчанию. Скрипт просто убивался и соответственно js "какбы получал" пустой ответ.

Comment: @Knyaz71 Нет у меня нет такого долгого запроса. У меня максимум 3сек и убивается. А если полностью работает то выполняется 9.1сек, но это на тестовом сервере, на продовском всё в несколько раз быстрее. Просто я боюсь, что эта проблема перекочует на прод, а это не есть хорошо. Мне бы главное как-нибуть отловить и обработать эту ошибку и всё будет хорошо.